# Magento how to add JS tracking code to specific category pages and checkout pages

Tags: javascript, magento

We are using Floodlight which consist of JS tracking codes that need to be added on individual pages. I need to add a snippet of JS code on the home page, checkout and thank you page. But the biggest problem is, how do I add custom JS code to the category pages?

These pages are dynamic and there are no single template to add for each individual page. I can't find any where in Manage Categories in the admin how to add this either.

Anyone have any clue? Or do I need to add a module to allow me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new `core/template` block to the category pages via the corresponding layout handles, that would display a custom JS code depending on what's given to it, and then assign it per-category values by using the `Custom Layout Update` category field from the `Custom Design` tab